# nodejs - passport done call back

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js

I am wondering what does done call back do in the following code. Is it the way to extract message from jwt payload? Does it return `user` in this scenario? If so, how can I access this returned user? Where is it stored?

```
module.exports = function(passport) {  
  var opts = {};
  opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
  opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
  passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.id}, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err, false);
      }
      if (user) {
        done(null, user);
      } else {
        done(null, false);
      }
    });
  }));
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

done is a method called internally by the strategy implementation.

Then it navigates you,  to one of the three methods, **success / error / fail**.

Each of these options may calls to the `next`.

When `success` is called, it can attach the user to the request or do other things, depending on your needs

Read the below link for a complete understanding:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L80

Comment: Thank you @Kevin RED. But how can I access the `user` argument passed to success?

Comment: I mean, you are using done(null,user).  That is the success method being called. You get your user once it is a success. In other cases, say error, you are passing in a false method. If its useful and complete please upvote and mark this post as complete